# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Database Connection Issue After Moving Website to AWS EC2 and RDS

I recently moved my website from a local environment to AWS EC2 and RDS.

After launching the EC2 instance and RDS, my website is partially functional on the EC2 instance. While GET methods work fine, I encounter issues with POST methods, specifically related to the database connection.

Previously, I used MySQL Workbench to create a new connection using the username 'manager' via localhost. However, after transitioning to AWS EC2 and RDS, I updated the connection details to use a new username 'admin' and set the host to the endpoint provided by Amazon.

I updated the application.properties file in my Java application with the following configuration.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://management-system.ctyygqiegjpe.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/management?serverTimezone=Australia/Sydney&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Despite these changes, the database is not functioning properly, and I'm encountering a 'whitelabel error (500)'.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Erm, the error message is quite explicit: either your username and/or password is incorrect or the user does not have access to the requested resource.

Comment: @Shadow Thank you for your comment. I've tried a few things. I granted privileges to the user 'manager', and I can connect to MySQL Workbench using the user ID and password I set when I created the instance. Additionally, I've added port 3306 to my security group. The website functions properly with my localhost, including the database-related pages, but the problem occurs on my EC2 instance server.

Comment: are you connecting to localhost instead of RDS instance ?

Comment: @KavinduVindika Hello. I am running it on my ec2 instance.

ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-26:~/stock-management-system/build/libs$ java -jar management-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: are you sure, that you've configured the application to use RDS instance url instead of localhost ? it's questionable, why it says `localhost`.
Can you check if there's any issue when triggering post requests, since you've told that get requests are working fine.

Comment: @KavinduVindika I configured the 'application.properties' file with the endpoint provided by RDS.

Comment: If you app runs on the same unstance as mysql, then localhost in the mysql error message us fine. However, if your code runs on a different host to the rds instance, then your code connects to your localhost mysql database, explaining the error messge. You probably do not have an admin user locally.